# How can I disable Scala Play json's backslash escape in `JsObject.toString()`?

Tags: scala, play-json

I cannot find a way to print a single backslash as a single backslash within Play json.  Is this something possible?

```scala
scala> val k = """abc\edf"""
val k: String = abc\edf

scala> JsString(k)
val res80: play.api.libs.json.JsString = "abc\\edf"

scala> JsString(k).toString()
val res81: String = "abc\\edf"     // <--- additional "\" appears

scala> JsString(k).as[String]
val res82: String = abc\edf        // <--- this is the string that I need

scala> Json.stringify(JsString(k))
val res86: String = "abc\\edf"

scala> Json.asciiStringify(JsString(k))
val res90: String = "abc\\edf"

scala> Json.prettyPrint(JsString(k))
val res92: String = "abc\\edf"
```

Normally this would be fine as I can just use `as[String]`.  But if this value is within object I cannot use `as[String]`.

```scala
scala> JsObject(Seq("abc" -> JsObject(Seq("edf" -> JsString("""111\2222"""))))).toString()
val res99: String = {"abc":{"edf":"111\\2222"}}    // <-- I have no ideea how I can print single back slash here
```

I want to convert JsObject to a string without backslash escaping, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"abc\edf"` is not valid JSON, as per the JSON specs:
https://www.json.org/json-en.html

`\` can only be followed by `"`, `\`, `/`, `b`, `f`, `n`, `r`, `t`, or `u`+4 hexadecimal digits representing a Unicode code point.

[image]

Play Framework simply isn't allowing you to output malformed JSON.

More specifically, a single `\` *must* be escaped in JSON to `\\`. But if you `parse` the JSON back into Scala, it'll get unescaped back to `\`.

```
val in = """abc\edf"""
val out = Json.parse(Json.stringify(JsString(in))).as[String]
```

`out` should look like this `abc\edf`.

To extract a specific property out of an object, use Play's [JSON traversal mechanism](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJson#Traversing-a-JsValue-structure).

```
scala> val obj = JsObject(Seq("abc" -> JsObject(Seq("edf" -> JsString("""111\2222""")))))
val obj: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"abc":{"edf":"111\\2222"}}

scala> (obj \ "abc" \ "edf").as[String]
val res0: String = 111\2222
```